Do I have to place a gap in the GND plane to reduce noise from DCDC?
In the past I made few designs with switching power supplies and I'm aware about the needs to keep traces short and with low impedance (i.e. where possible use filled zone instead of tracks) and to keep feedback network far from the switching one.
My current design requires two TPS62933 to provide a 12V and 3.3V from an input voltage between 14V and 18V.
The 12V rail will power a few air valves and the 3.3V an MCU (ESP32) and some other peripherals (NFC, ADC, pressure sensors).
Here my schematics:

and here the related layout:

I know it's not very clear to read, but I hope it's enough to answer to my question.
I'm using a two layers FR4 PCB and both sides are filled with GND planes (I'm going to add more GND vias when the routing will be complete).
I tried to follow the reference layout available in the datasheet (page 41) as much as possible.
I will be glad to receive any suggestion to improve my design, but my specific question is:
Is it ok to leave the power supply section "buried" in the GND planes of the whole board?
Or should I place a gap all around it leaving just a connection close to the input connector? Something like this rough example:

My concern is to avoid spreading the fast switching edges across the board.
Of course the GND is the same. I'm talking about an isolation, just a gap to force the current to flow where I want (of course, if I'm right!).
By the time I wrote this question I read this answer and I'm going to remove the top GND plane under the inductors.

What are you powering with those buck converters?

@JonathanS. question updated, thanks

If you put a gap in a ground plane, it is important that no conductors cross the gap. When I do this, I have a "bridge" where the grounds are connected together, and all other conductors between the subsystems cross between them.

Two things to remember:  if you cut the ground plane you should not route signals over the cut and fast transients on the ground plane travel together with fast transients on signal layers.
The first means that if you want to cut the plane like that, you should route the power connections down the bottom over the ground plane so that you don't route over the cut.  The second means that if you route the power out the bottom, any high frequency signals will flow under those traces down the bottom.  This is true even if you make the ground plane continuous, so in reality splitting the ground plane doesn't accomplish anything, at least at high frequencies.
Rather than cut the ground plane, try to route the return currents back to the switching supply by orienting the supply and the power traces to/from it such that they do not pass over sensitive electronics.  In this case I think you have actually done that fairly well by having the connector in the corner, the switching converter right next to it, and then the consumers of those supplies perpendicular to one another.

Without paying much attention to the layout of the converters, this answer merely regards the use of ground planes and slots.
What slotting the plane does, is relieve current flow in that location.
This necessarily increases (high frequency / AC) voltage drop in the same area.
Where that voltage drops, and whether it couples into anything, is critical.
Consider:

There are current loops in the area of the converters (blue). I haven't drawn these in any particular location, just that there are generally dipole (or higher order, but those drop off more rapidly with distance).
There is a common point by J1, so we can consider this a ground reference for the rest of the board. (There may be some induction along the narrow strip along the bottom-left, whether due to fields from the converters, or external sources, but we can ignore those for now.)  Due to the current loops, there is a voltage drop along this slot, more or less increasing along its length (blue +/-).
Isolating ground currents of a converter is fine, in and of itself, but where you connect to it matters critically.  See green numbers: these cross the slot, introducing the full voltage drop in that part of the slot, in series with the signal/trace itself.
In general, traces crossing slots is an extremely bad idea.
You could route traces this way (green):

which will need some allowances for routing, how far back along the slot the traces get bunched up at, etc.
And probably the common connection should be moved to the middle, along with J1 (since we don't want to put J1 in a position where it's transmitting additional common-mode (between-grounds) voltage into the cable).  Or if J1 position is fixed, perhaps something more like this:

still with adjustments to keep induction away from the thin web that J1 is tied to the bulk of the board with, and generally moving around components for better placement.
In summary: if you don't know exactly what you're doing, slotting grounds is almost certainly a bad idea.  Solid ground plane gives the lowest impedance between points on the board, and component placement and trace routing control where currents flow within that plane.  Keep large and fast currents in short, tight loops, keep them distant from connectors, and keep connectors grouped close together, to minimize emissions.


... to force the current to flow where I want ...

Watch out for this one. The current from a source needs to return to the source. Where you think it should go and where it does go can be very different. A major task in board layout is to allow the current to travel its own path in a plane without cutting slots in the plane. The path should be as short as possible with the smallest loop area as possible.
Five points:

Place the user interactive parts first. This is a hard constraint that must be met. Don't leave them until the last.
Plan a power distribution network so that all the return currents form a small loop area.
Plan how the circuit groups flow around the board keeping constraints in 1 and 2 in mind. Don't have groups cris-cross each other. Even in the ground plane.
Keep the area of the current loops (for each component) as small as possible. Even in the ground plane.
When a component is placed, visualize how the current leaves the component and the path that it takes to return to that component. Make that path as short as possible.


The 12V rail will power a few air valves and the 3.3V an...

Remember that these "rails" have a "sibling rails" called the return path. When planning the outbound path also plan (at the same time) the return path even if it is in a ground plane. You won't get it right the first time. It is an iterative process.

Is it ok to leave the power supply section "buried" in the GND planes of the whole board?

Buried means out-of-sight, out-of-mind. Don't do that. Observe (plan) how the power supply currents flow about the board and through the planes. Don't leave it to chance. Make certain that these currents do not interfere with signal currents but support the components that generate them. Without making cuts in the plane.

should I place a gap all around it leaving just a connection close to the input connector?

This is probably a bad idea. A proper layout should not need this cut. The currents should naturally flow in that way. If they don't then change the layout. Remember, that return currents naturally tend to return along the same path as the outbound currents. This is especially true at higher frequencies. Plan the layout to allow that to happen naturally.

My concern is to avoid spreading the fast switching edges across the board.

These edges don't just spread across the board like marbles on a tile floor. Fast edges contain high frequencies and so dearly want to follow a return path in the plane close to the outbound path. Make the path the edge must follow as short as possible with the smallest area. Fast edges on a long path need a transmission line. Fast edges of a SMPS need very tight small loop areas and kept  local by using decoupling capacitors to support the fast need for current. Plan these loops for each component, fast, slow or dc.

Of course the GND is the same.

This one often trips folks up. The ground plane is resistive and inductive. There is capacitance from every trace to the ground plane. Different regions of the plane have different current densities at different frequencies. Don't treat GND as the same every where. You need to visualize threads of current criss-crossing the plane and your job is to straighten them out without cutting the plane. On a dense two-layer board this task is challenging.
Of course if the second layer requires a signal trace then that is a cut in the plane. Be sure it doesn't interfere with another loop's return current.

I'm going to remove the top GND plane under the inductors.

Perhaps the ground plane on the opposite layer under the inductor should be removed as well.
I will let you decide how my answer can guide your own impression of your pcb layout.
Remember that board layout is driven by the electronics of the printed circuit board itself.
